# How to access docker container through hostname?(from my host pc)

Tags: docker, ubuntu, hostname, docker-network

(I'm doing this just for practice, to know docker.)

My host PC is `ubuntu 18.04 LTS`.
And this is my `docker-compose` file(default network mode is bridge).

```
version: "2"
services:
  zookeeper1:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
  zookeeper2:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
  zookeeper3:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
```

In docker container, they can find each other.

```sh
> docker container exec -it 8b1c2b412989 ping zookeeper2
PING zookeeper2 (172.19.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from setup-zookeeper-kafka_zookeeper2_1.setup-zookeeper-kafka_default (172.19.0.3): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.097 ms
64 bytes from setup-zookeeper-kafka_zookeeper2_1.setup-zookeeper-kafka_default (172.19.0.3): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.129 ms
```

But when I tried to my host PC, it doesn't work

```sh
> ping zookeeper2
ping: zookeeper2: Name or service not known

> ping 8b1c2b412989 # container id also doesn't work
ping: 8b1c2b412989: Name or service not known
```

Ping with `ip`, it works well.

```
> ping 172.19.0.3
PING 172.19.0.3 (172.19.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.19.0.3: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.142 ms
64 bytes from 172.19.0.3: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.046 ms
```

I added `hostname` property, it still doesn't work.

```
version: "2"
services:
  zookeeper1:
    hostname: zookeeper1
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
  zookeeper2:
    hostname: zookeeper2
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
  zookeeper3:
    hostname: zookeeper3
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
```

How can I access container with hostname from my host PC?
Now, I only can do with `ports` options.(or I have to write static IP address)

What this I am thinking wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens as Giga commented. If you don't have the hostname in your /etc/hosts there is no magic here.

If you need to ping for healthcheck you can use [docker-compose's healthcheck](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#healthcheck)
So, with it you can always look your zookeepers if they are alive or not.

If you insist that you need to ping with hostname, I recommend roll up your sleeves, and make a bash script using docker format like ...

```
docker ps --format "table {{.ID}}\t{{.Ports}}"
```

And then with every containerid with the container Name do:

```
docker inspect <containerid> and extract the IP like you have [here.][2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Docker does not updates your host /etc/hosts file automatically, so you can`t access fro host machine via hostname. 
You can manually write wrapper for docker-compose, which will update host machine's /etc/hosts file.
But another question is, why you would need it.